# Couchbase create Immutable property, or meta info which holds created date time

Tags: replace, updates, couchbase, immutability, createjs

When creating document i am adding a property called “createdOn” and saving it to the couchbase server this field hold the current date time,

```
 CURL POST

   {
        "fName":"x",
        "lName":"y",
        "createOn":"2018-10-10:T12:45:12Z"
    }
```

wanted to know how i can make this property immutable (update call should not change the “createdOn”, even if user change then should get error message), is there a way using meta Info by which i can do it ? instead of creating this field inside document, create as meta Info ?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly believe that this feature is not supported yet. I have never seen any mention of it in the docs, plus some SDKs docs mention that you should handle immutability by encapsulating your fields properly in the application side.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/